# I need to prove this set theory relation (The question is about big cap)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$ A \cup \bigcap_{S \in F}S \subseteq  \bigcap_{S \in F}(A \cup S)$$

My try:

Let $x \in A \cup \bigcap_{S \in F}S$ then it splits into 2 possible options:

1. If $x \in A$ then of course $x \in A \cup S$ for all $S \in F~~~$ **(*)** and thus $x \in \bigcap_{S \in F}(A \cup S) ~~~~~(**)$
2. If $x \in \bigcap_{S \in F}S$ then $x \in S$ for every $S \in F$ and thus $x \in A \cup S~~~$ **(*)**
   for every $S \in F$ which is the definition of $ \bigcap_{S \in F}(A \cup S)~~~$  (**)

I am really not sure about this, because the reasoning between (*) and (**) seems kind of weak, and probably misses the whole point of this question... I really don't understand how to solve it other than what I just wrote..

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Looks fine to me. Note, though, that this is an equality of sets, not just an inclusion. You basically show that in your argument, anyway.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thanks! so the reasoning isn't weak? would you change something in there? Or it's 100% in your opinion?

Comment: @StackOfMeow I mean... the proof works. Rather than asking others what sort of artificial, ultimately aesthetic standards you ought to live up to, I recommend thoroughly examining your own arguments for flaws. Sometimes it takes a while, but learning to check your own proofs is a billion times more valuable than learning what a particular teacher wants a given proof to look like - which I guess is the only true measuring stick for what 100 % would mean. Your proof is both short, clear and does not contain any questionable inferences.